# Make navigation height scale with size of main content

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get my navigation menu to fill in the page but I haven't succeeded:

[image]

I want the green menu section to fill the page down to the footer.

Here is my html:

```
    <div id="navigation">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx">Contact Admin</asp:HyperLink>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx">About</asp:HyperLink>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/JobDescriptionForm.aspx">Job Questionnaire</asp:HyperLink>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="additionalTools">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="LeftNavCont" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mainContent">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFooter" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</form>
```

and css:

```
#header {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: #009900;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

#mainContent {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I tried making the whole page 100% heights and then also the navigation div but it didn't work. manually making the height longer with px (800px) but it makes it not dynamic. How do I accomplish what I want? Thanks!

Comment: try height: 100vh;  Partial support in IE9+

Comment: That doesn't keep the menu the same size as the body

Comment: If you set html,body { height: 100vh; } it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

#navigation {
height:auto;
min-height:100%;
}
```